# How to make a tab active from the beginning in Angular Bootstrap UI?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm trying to make one of the tabs active (tabs are already in the template), depending on some url params. Unfortunately, it always make active by default **the first one found in the html template**, even if I use a ng-repeat as in this example.

This doesn't work:

```
$scope.tabs = {
        title2: {active:false, content:"Hello world 2!"},
        title3: {active:false, content:"Hello world 3!"},
        title4: {active:false, content:"Hello world 4!"}
    }
    $scope.tabs.title4.active = true;
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexrada/KFAXH/5/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the initial static tab in angular bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695629/setting-the-initial-static-tab-in-angular-bootstrap). A bug has been filed: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/678

Comment: The duplicate is spot on. See @Thomas's answer in the duplicate. Also [Issue #747](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/747) and [Pull #834](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/834) are what seem to be the definitive fixes (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the $routeParams service inside your controller and set the the $scope active value from it. something along these lines:

```
.controller('MyTabCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.tabs[$routeParams.active].active = true;
})
```

where the URL would be `/?active=title4`

you will also need to set up your $routeProvider service.
I'll see if I can get a fork of your JSFiddle to work once it becomes usable again (it's soooo slow currently...)

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed, you need to use basic concept of ui.bootstrap First Tab will be active by default

Html Code :

```
<div ng-controller="MyTabCtrl">
    <tabset>
        <tab heading="title1">{{tabs.title1.content}}</tab>
        <tab heading="title2">{{tabs.title2.content}}</tab>
        <tab heading="title3">{{tabs.title3.content}}</tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

script code

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']).
controller("MyTabCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.panes = [
        {title:"First", content:"Hello world!"},
        {title:"Second", content:"Bonjour monde!"},
        {title:"Second", content:"Bonjour monde!"}
    ];
    $scope.tabs = {
        title1: {content:"Hello world 1!"},
        title2: {content:"Hello world 2!"},
        title3: {content:"Hello world 3!"}
    }
  // $scope.tabs.active = true;
});
```

Working Example : http://jsfiddle.net/KFAXH/28/