# Angular bootstrap lazy loaded tabs , autoselecting the tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using tabs of angular bootstrap ui. I have overriden the tabs directive so as to perform lazy loading of data 
Plunkr link for the same : http://plnkr.co/edit/uAb3TrKtxoPPXx8mekRz?p=preview

The lazy loading works perfectly fine. However I need to dynamically select the tabs based on certain properties.

For example, I tried the following

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="TabCtrl">

     <tabset>
         <tab title="Tab 1" template-url="tab1.html"  active="{{tab1stat}}"></tab>
         <tab title="Tab 2" template-url="tab2.html" active="{{tab2stat}}"></tab>
     </tabset>

</div>
```

and in my controller.js I tried setting the active property for the tabs in the scope

```
app.controller('TabCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    // $dialogs.error('t est');
    $scope.tab1stat=false;
    $scope.tab2stat=true  
  }
]);
```

I tried accessing the scope variables in the html, however the tab directive seems to get rendered before the controller is initialized.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Also I need to refresh the tab with a different html. For example my tab1.html will have a few buttons which will render some html pages. All these pages need to be rendered in the same tab.Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the curly braces from the active attribute binding so it looks like so: active="tab2stat".  You should also not be binding to primitives to avoid the prototypal inheritance gotcha.

***EDIT***
The angular ui bootstrap library is watching the active attribute like so:

```
scope.$parent.$watch($parse(attrs.active), function (value) {
  alert(value);
});
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/pwXOz1O4Wb0RZsi3nPlC?p=preview

Comment: I tried doing that, however when I tried to read the active attribute in my directive, it reads the value of active as tab1stat=false.I also tried setting a timeout as specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695629/setting-the-initial-static-tab-in-angular-bootstrap . Howeevr still it does not seem to work.Plunkr link for the same http://plnkr.co/edit/VABthzUwp50QpS16Gwuy?p=preview